# Python How to count intersection of a specific value in both array?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two array A, B which both have values of [0 , 1 , 2] (same size) 
I want to count the intersection of index for value 1. Basically in another word, I want to check the precision of value 1 base on array A.

So far I have tried map function but it doesnt work.

```
temp = list(map(lambda x,y: (x is y) == 1 ,A ,B))
```

However the result is not what I expected. Can you show some advice or example on how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5])
print(np.sum(list(map(lambda x,y: (x==y==1) , x, y))))
```

output:

```
2
```

**Tensorflow code:**

```
elems = (np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5]), np.array([0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5]))
alternate = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.math.logical_and(tf.equal(x[0], 1), tf.equal(x[0], x[1])), elems, dtype=tf.bool)
print(alternate)
print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(alternate, tf.float32)))
```

output:

```
tf.Tensor([False True False False True False False False True False False True False False], shape=(14,), dtype=bool)
tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Yes thats what i was looking for. Thank you !